# Change directory for saving a file and return to old directory

Tags: bash

I wrote a very little and basic script which compares two files and writes all matching lines into a file.

I now want to secure, that no matter from which directory/working directory you run the bash script, the file is stored in the directory where the script is located.

```
#! /bin/bash
typeset -i count=1
typeset -i useable_counter=1
file="Fundstellen.txt"
curDir=`pwd`
wantedDir="/Users/Stephan/Documents/Schule/SYT/Skripting/bin/Uebungen"
echo `pushd ${wantedDir}`

if [ -e $file ]; then
 echo `chmod 777 ${file}`
 echo `rm ${file}`
fi

echo `touch ${file}`

while read pass; do
 pass_nr=`echo $pass | cut -d ":" -f 3`
 while read groups; do
  group_nr=`echo $groups | cut -d ":" -f 3`

  if [ "$pass_nr" = "$group_nr" ]; then
   if [ $count -gt 15 ]; then
    echo "#$useable_counter: $pass in $groups" >> $file
    useable_counter=$useable_counter+1
   fi
   count=$count+1
  fi
 done < /etc/group
done < /etc/passwd

echo `chmod 444 $file`
echo `popd`
echo "Writing done!"
```

That's my script with the pushd command to get to the directory in which the script is located and popd should return.

But still, the output file is created in the directory/working directory, from where the script is launched.
What do I have to change so it'll work? I already tried to use normal `cd` to change the directory, that's why the variable `curDir` stores the starting directory.

Comment: Which are you echoing the contents of the subshells that would already be echoed...? Every command does not need to be in backticks.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, the answer below says I should put it in backticks, you refuse to?

Comment: Whatever you are trying to acoomplish, **`chmod 777 is wrong** and a security problem.

Comment: No, the answer also says the backticks are wrong.

Comment: Yea, that may be true @tripleee. I'm very new to bash scripting and I was told, that any command which is a normal bash command is written in `echo` with the command in backticks

Comment: @Stöger Whoever told you that has no idea what they are doing.

Comment: @123 haha yea I guess that he has no idea what he's doing. When do I need backticks in my script then? What is their purose of use?

Comment: @Stöger If you are using bash then don't ever use backticks. Use the newer and more friendly `$()`. For more info on uses look here http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html

Comment: @123 so using backticks is the same as putting the command for the terminal in brackets ?

Comment: @Stöger: Backticks and `$()` have the same effect: they make it possible to capture output of a command. If you don't need to capture the output, don't use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By putting `pushd` into backticks, you're running it in a subshell. No subshell can change the current working directory of its parent shell.

Just call

```
pushd "$wantedDir"
```

directly, and same with `popd`.

Comment: He means that's the problem, since your file creation isn't done in the same subshell

Comment: @Aaron could you please answer the question with the working code ?

Answer (score 2):

Your script is a hopeless mess.  All you need to produce output in the named file is

```
command >/Users/Stephan/Documents/Schule/SYT/Skripting/bin/Uebungen/Fundstellen.txt
```

Generally, very few scripts need to explicitly `cd` and fewer still would need to `pushd` and `popd` -- these commands are almost exclusively for interactive use.

The loop where you read all of the `group` file for every entry in the `passwd` file is extremely inefficient, especially when the purpose of the inner loop seems to be to find only a small subset of the records in the file.  Very often, when you see `while read`, you want Awk instead.  Here is a simple framework for doing that.

```
awk -F : 'NR==FNR { ++p[$3]; next }
    FNR > 15 && $3 in p { print "#" ++i ": " $3 " in " $0 }' /etc/passdwd /etc/group
```

It's not clear what the 15 is supposed to accomplish.  Is it a bug in your script, or is the intent to only skip the first 15 lines on the first iteration?

Comment: It's only to skip the first 15 lines, thanks for your answer!

Comment: The first 15 lines of the first file, or of every file?  If the former, try `NR > 15` instead.